# Python NLTK tokenize sentence with wrong syntax from human errors

Tags: python, nltk

I am looking for a way to handle sentence tokenizing task well.

I have this text extracted from a human written review for a restaurant

```
Nevertheless, the soup enhances the prawns well.In contrast, the fish offered is fresh and well prepared.
```

Note that, the period that is the boundary of first  sentence is not separated by space. It is result from human error in writing. There are many sentences that were written like this that I can't ignore this one case.

So far I tried nltk sentence tokenizer in python but does not work as expected.

```
>>>import nltk.data
>>>tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>>>sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
>>>sentences
['Nevertheless, the soup enhances the prawns well.In contrast, the fish offered is fresh and well prepared.']
```

My expectation is it should be able to split the text into two sentences

```
['Nevertheless, the soup enhances the prawns well.', 'In contrast, the fish offered is fresh and well prepared.']
```

Any help is appreciated in advance

Comment: *"does not work as expected"* - what did you expect, and what happened instead? *"does not tweak in my case"* - what change did you make, and what happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i updated my question. I decided to remove the tweak link because it seems not relevant to the problem here.

Comment: Clearly the tokenizer expects valid English text. Have you tried preprocessing to split the sentences, e.g. [`re.sub(r'(.([A-Z]))', r'. \2', text)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)?

Comment: What if there's a period that is not intended to be a sentence stop? Like `The soup didn't taste well at all! Please contact me at somebody@example.com to get a detailed report.`

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for suggestion. I did take the regex and preprocess. It solves for my case above, but the regex of detecting capital later after "." will make abbreviation text mess up. For example if the text is "I am looking for Mr. J.Chamber. Do you see him?"

Comment: @sovanlandy Actually, I would expect that to read `"Mr. J. Chamber"`, so I don't think that's a problem! Acronyms with periods in (e.g. `"S.H.I.E.L.D"`) might be a problem, though.

Comment: @ComputerFellow it isn't perfect, I'll admit, but it wouldn't choke on your example - I've specified a capital letter following the period.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's right. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe just want to let you know that from your suggestion, I came up with this preprocess regex on text `re.sub(r'(\w{2})([.!?]{1,})(\w{1})', r'\1\2 \3', text)`. It passed testcase like this `I work for agent S.H.E.L.D and it is awesome!!I love it.`  It is not perfect yet, but good enough for cover most cases. Thanks again.

Comment: @sovanlandy note that `{1,}` can be replaced with `+` and `{1}` left out entirely (see http://regex101.com/r/pU4jK7/1).

Comment: @jonrsharpe noted with thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use regex for preprocessing of the text. The regex i use was.

```
re.sub(r'(\w{2})([.!?]+)(\w+)', r'\1\2 \3', text)
```

It has 3 groups. Group 1 is  before the punctuation `(\w{2})`. Group 2 is the punctuation which can be `[!?.]`  and can repeat more than once so it is `([.!?]{1,})`. Group 3 is the next word after punctuation which can anywhere be 1 or more character word like "I" `(\w{1})` .

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. If this is the only problem with your input, you're on the right track. If you discover more and more and it grows out of hand, you might end up having to write your own tokenizer. But do look out for other things being split that you don't intend (e.g., have you thought about what will happen to `98.6`?)